# JAX-RS - package private classes

Tags: java, jax-rs

I'm using JAX-RS for exposing REST endpoints.

To maintain a good package state I'd like to have my DTO classes (the one I return as Json and accept from Json) as package-private.
Does JAX-RS require those classes to be always public?

I'd like to apply the same thing to my custom Exception Mapper (`@Provider` annotated).

Comment: yes. it is required.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha could you point out where in the documentation this is written? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Well, afaik they must be `public` ... But what prevents you from just trying it out?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I haven't setup the deploy environment yet. I couldn't find this info in the official standard so I asked here.

Comment: It will be up to the provider you are using. It won't be in the Jersey docs.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thanks. The project requires Apache CFX. Maybe there?

Comment: Note, that JAX-RS is a specification for doing REST communication. There are several implementation (e.g. Jersey or Resteasy) that require publicness of those classes.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Instinctively I tought the standard would have been clear about that. I'll check the Apache CFX docs.

Comment: Have you tried it? You could find out the answer by simply trying it.

Comment: @I'm going to setup a simpler project to try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to JAX-RS 2.0 specification (ch. 04, p. 27):

> 4.1.2    Constructors
>
> Provider classes that are instantiated by the JAX-RS runtime and MUST
>   have a public constructor for which the JAX-RS runtime can provide all
>   parameter values. Note that a zero argument constructor is permissible
>   under this rule.

Effectively `public` ctors can only exists in `public` classes.

As discussed, this is a vendor-specific question, but any vendor which allows registering package-private provider doesn't truly follow the specification.

Comment: This apply to the Provider part, not the DTO classes. But I'll accept this answer.